# Перемещение персонажа

Tags: unity3d

Учу unity, Пытаюсь создать 2d-игру. В уроках по unity твердые тела (`rigidbody`) перемещают с помощью `rigidbody2d.velocity`
Вопрос: почему нельзя перемещать с помощью `transform.position` или `transform.Translate`? 
Или перемещать можно, но не нужно?) Хотелось получить ответ на вопрос и дальше продолжать изучение unity.

Answer (score 4):

`transform.position` - это просто текущая позиция, Вы должны рассчитать новую позицию вручную.

`transform.Translate()` - передвигает объект на заданное расстояние, здесь Вы указываете только расстояние.

И в том, и в другом случае они передвигают сам объект, не принимая в расчет его физическое описание. В результате ломается вообще вся физическая симуляция, так как на следующем вызове `FixedUpdate()`, где рассчитывается физика, объект окажется вовсе не в той позиции, где это ожидается физическим движком.

`rigidbody.velocity` - меняет физическое описание объекта. Впрочем, это тоже нарушает физику, хотя и в меньшей степени - объект получит только другую скорость. Часто это терпимо.

`rigidbody.AddForce()` - это то, что реально нужно использовать для движения rigidbody. К сожалению, это мало где описано, а там есть множество нюансов.

Приведу один из вариантов кода для движения `rigidbody`, он вычисляет разницу между текущим и желаемым значениями `velocity` и применяет только эту разницу:

```
var velocityChange = desiredVelocity - _rigidbody.velocity;
_rigidbody.AddForce (velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

При этом, реальная скорость объекта может отличаться от желаемой в результате физической симуляции (например, при движении под гору или в гору).

Еще есть специальный компонент `CharacterController`. Двигать его нужно при помощи его собственных методов `SimpleMove()` и `Move()`.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `rigidbody` — это объект, для которого подключем физический контроллер, он сам умеет считать столкновения и все такое. Ну то есть можно задавать `transform.Translate`, но вам все равно прийдется где-то хранить скорость, как-то считать столкновения... Почему бы не оставить это для самого движка?

Comment: да я с радостью оставлю эту черную работу для движка) просто хотелось понять, в чем разница между этими функциями, а не просто писать rigidbody.velocity и т.д.

Comment: а между transform.Translate и transform.position разница какая?

Comment: `transform.Translate` — это функция, которая устанавливает новые координаты объекту. При этом по умолчанию она устанавливает их относительно текущего положения объекта, но можно указать другую точку отсчета.
<br/>
`transform.position` — это вектор с координатами. Вы его устанавливаете в редакторе, когда помещаете на карту новый объект. Его и изменяет `transform.Translate`

Comment: блин, все равно не пойму. что лучше всего использовать тогда translate или transform

Comment: я хорошо воспринимаю видеоуроки, читать не люблю и не понимаю, когда что-то читаю, к сожалению ((

Comment: http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=12527

Comment: блин, слонжно( пропадает мотивация учить в таких ситуациях

Comment: Какая-то у вас странная мотивация. Ну пересильте себя. Не всегда же на форумах спрашивать? Что будет, кагда начнете какой-то проект делать? Там иногда на форумы-то и не сунешься — коммерческая тайна.

Comment: Почитайте внимательно то, что я скинул. Там описывается реализация `transform.Translate`. Несложно видеть, что она изменяет `transform.position`.

Comment: float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
rb.valocity = Vector2.right * x * speed;
Вот такое вот перемещение объекта правильное?

Comment: да, если `speed` — максимальная скорость.
Если нужна плавность, можно использовать `lerp`